# How can I add on-platform parameter into a Xamarin Label?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Label xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
           x:Class="Japanese.Templates.MessageLabel" 
           FontSize="{DynamicResource MessageTextFontSize}" 
           TextColor="{DynamicResource FooterTextColor}" />
```

I would like to make it so that the `Property="FontFamily"` is set like this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
   <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5ProLight" />
   <On Platform="Android" Value="Font Awesome 5 Pro-Light-300.otf#FontAwesome5ProLight" />
</OnPlatform>
```

but how can I make this into a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, you can try. The platform syntax has changed in Xamarin.Forms 3.2 (I guess),

```
<Label xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
           x:Class="Japanese.Templates.MessageLabel" 
           FontSize="{DynamicResource MessageTextFontSize}" 
           TextColor="{DynamicResource FooterTextColor}">
           <Label.FontFamily>
                <OnPlatform
                    x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                    Android="Font Awesome 5 Pro-Light-300.otf#FontAwesome5ProLight"
                    iOS="FontAwesome5ProLight" />
            </Label.FontFamily>

</Label>
```

but the old syntax(mentioned in the question) will work as well if you want to use that.

Comment: This does not work on later platforms. Can someone change the accepted answer to the one below which works?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Label xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
           x:Class="Japanese.Templates.MessageLabel" 
           FontSize="{DynamicResource MessageTextFontSize}" 
           TextColor="{DynamicResource FooterTextColor}">
        <Label.FontFamily>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
               <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5ProLight" />
               <On Platform="Android" Value="Font Awesome 5 Pro-Light-300.otf#FontAwesome5ProLight" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Label.FontFamily>
    </Label>
```

I'm not sure I understood your question properly, but is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

for better use define font family in  style and apply wherever you want

```
 <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="MediumFont">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="fonts/HKGrotesk_Medium.ttf#HK Grotesk" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Fonts/HKGrotesk_Medium.ttf#HK Grotesk" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="HKGrotesk-Medium" />
        </OnPlatform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This In App.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Auction.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                        Android="FontAwesome5ProLight.otf#FontAwesome5ProLight" 
                        iOS="FontAwesome5ProLight" 
                        WinPhone="20" 
                        x:Key="FontFamilyName" />


            <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource FontFamilyName}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#000000"/>
            </Style>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Use in Any Page Of Your App 
in Xaml

```
  <Label x:Name="Register" Text="Registeration"  HorizontalTextAlignment ="Center" FontSize="20"  Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}">
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" ></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
```

and cs

```
   label.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["labelStyle"];
```